# How can I validate input fields with Twitter Bootstrap 2.0 and apply error class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a field like the following:

```
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="control-label" for="lname">Last Name</label>
    <div class="controls">
        <input class="span3" type="text" id="lname" name="lname" placeholder="Last Name" value=""/>
    </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying the following jquery to validate some input and add the error class if needed:

```
var div = $("#lname").parent("div.control-group");
....
div.removeClass("success");
div.addClass("error");
```

Ideally I need to loop through several input and select fields to do my validation.

My current code isn't adding the error class.  Any idea why?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use `parents` method instead of `parent` as

```
var div = $("#lname").parents("div.control-group");
div.removeClass("success");
div.addClass("error");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#form-register').validate({ errorElement: 'span', errorClass:'help-inline', highlight:    function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).parent().parent().addClass('error');
    }, unhighlight: function (element, errorClass) {
        $(element).parent().parent().removeClass('error');
    }});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use This [jQuery-Live-Form-Validation-For-Twitter-Bootstrap](https://github.com/alexbevi/jQuery-Live-Form-Validation-For-Twitter-Bootstrap)

When you include js files use this code below

```
jQuery(function(){
            jQuery('#lname').validate({expression: "if (VAL) return true; else return false;",
            message: "Please Enter Your Last Name"});
        });
```